# Suing a Cellular Company that Charged Me for Years Without My Knowledge

Tags: civil-law, small-claims-court, rules-of-court, legal-research, civil-legal-system

I am planning to sue a cellular company for charging me (for two phone numbers) for 10 years after a cutoff request. I contacted the company, and they admitted to wrongly charging me but only for one number and offered me a reimbursement - which's about 1/3 of the whole charged amount. Now I want to know how to make the legal argument that the sole fact of admitting to wrongly charging me for one number increases the likeability that the company did the same thing with the second number. 
* I am filing a small claims lawsuit.

Thanks, and if you need more clarifications about the issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to know how to make the legal argument that the sole fact of admitting to wrongly charging me for one number increases the likeability that the company did the same thing with the second number.

There isn’t one. You need to prove each allegation on its own merits. Admission of liability for one wrong does not amount to admission for all wrongs alleged. Nor does it allow the inference to be drawn of general dishonesty.

Comment: Or doesn't it at least bring into questioning the credibility of the company? Also, given the fact that I managed both numbers, and I would have not cut off one of them - and subscribe to another carrier - without doing so with the other.

Comment: @elias-98 No, it doesn't work that way. The fact that I admit to one offence/mistake/wrong has nothing to do with if I committed another.

Comment: @elias-98 - Not sure why you think it would - they admitted to their mistake and rectified it, why would that imply poor credibility?

Comment: There _might_ be a link, but it doesn't appear in the question. An example could be that the two numbers are billed as one product. As the claimant, you have the burden to show the association.

Comment: @MSalters both numbers were included in the same bill. Is that a possible link?

Comment: @colmde maybe they are trying to get away with it with the lowest possible cost? That they tried to persuade me to take an immediate sum of money?

Comment: @elias-98: That's a weaker link. After all, it's already established that the same person was billed (i.e. you).

Comment: @elias-98: Of course they offer an immediate sum of money. That is how you usually compensate for overcharging. It appears that you do not have your dispute clearly defined.

Comment: The issue has many more aspects to it, I just included the ones I thought were tangible to my question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @elias-98 - That may be the case, but if it is you'll have to come up with separate proof of this. The fact that they paid you and admitted their mistake does nothing to suggest this or damage their credibility. (It may even help their credibility a little, i.e. someone might think "Here's an honest company who admits when they're wrong and pays what they owe")